# Fortran error: "Cannot read from a file opened for WRITE"

Tags: file, io, fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I am writing a Fortran code which does some pretty straightforward (I thought) reading and processing of data.  The relevant parts look like

```
module mymod

integer :: funit

contains

subroutine initialize()
character(len=64) :: newline
funit=10
! notice I am specifying a "read" here
open(unit=funit,file='mydata.txt',status='old',action='read')
do i = 1,100
  read(funit,*) newline
! process newline ....
  if ( ... certain conditions ... ) call initialize_subset(i)
enddo
end subroutine


subroutine initialize_subset(n)
character(len=64) :: newline
integer :: n
read(funit,*) newline  ! <--- right here gives an error
! ... process newline
end subroutine

end module
```

When the execution gets to that second `read`, the one in subroutine `initialize_subset`, it fails with the error  "Fortran runtime error: Cannot read from file opened for WRITE"  What is going wrong?  Surely I don't need to open the file again in the second routine?  Notice that `funit` is a module variable and is not local to either subroutine, and that the file was opened with `action` "read".  I am compiling with gfortran.

Comment: Can you create a program which exhibits the same problem?  Unit numbers are global, but my first question would be whether your calls are in the expected order.

Comment: put `write(*,*)'reading unit',funit` in front of the read.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please provide a complete program. Also note that list directed input (`*` format) will only give you the *first record* in each line, not the complete line. To get the first line (or 64 chars of it), use `'(a)'`.

Comment: Without a compilable program we can't test it, please consider creating a minimal example of your issue.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either (gfortran gcc-4.-8-5), it runs fine.

Comment: @agentp  Somehow, funit gets set to 0 in the called subroutine.

Comment: That's what I'd have guessed from the error message. You are trying to read from standard error.  You must have some issue with the module variable going out of scope, but that is impossible to diagnose from this code fragment. Try putting `use mymod` in your main program if its not there already.   You should say your specific compiler version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to not have the problem pass `funit` to the routine which needs to read the same file.

```
if ( ... certain conditions ... ) call initialize_subset(i, funit)
```

---

However, the code posted in the question runs for me. Until more is provided I cannot look for the reason for the reported behavior (nor test whether the above bypasses it, even as I believe that it should).

Comment: `funit` is declared for the module and, therefore, accessible to all subroutines in the module. There is no need to explicitly pass it to the subroutine...

Comment: @AlexanderVogt  Yes, of course.  But why would its value in that subroutine be the "10" from another one?  (Is it?)  I think that it's getting initialized to whatever it does and it is not referring to the resource. (Come to think of it -- it should be initialized at the module level, and its assignment in one routine can't affect the other?) With `implicit none` I meant good practice.  But I tnink that it'd solve this, too.  For one thing, I don't see how this can fail if it is passed.

Comment: You are right in that their is something happening with `funit` that we do not know about. OP didn't tell us. While your answer tries to circumvent the symptoms, it does not fix the cause.  Using `implicit none` is always good advice, but is not the issue here.

Comment: No. `funit` is a module variable, and as such a "global" variable accessible to all module functions/subroutines. If one subroutine assigns a value to it, all other subroutines can read that value out. `funit` is in the scope of the module, not the individual subroutines. Since the module does not go out of scope, the variable value is preserved.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt  Alright, yes.  Apparently, that gets broken somehow.  I'll reword this slightly and leave it as is until i figure this out. (I believe it will bypass the problem but it is true that it doesn't address it.)  I am curious now.

Comment: Only if you declare it a second time. This issue has nothing to do with `implicit none`.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt  Ah.  That's what I meant by mentioning `implicit none` -- I always declare in subroutines so I am not sure what (exactly) to expect here.  Thank you.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Have looked the code over again just to be sure.  Nothing else is happening with `funit`.  Not in the code anyway.  If anything is changing, it's either something in Fortran that I don't understand (hence my question) or its some kind of compiler problem.  I'm figuring the former is more likely.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @bob.sacamento please provide a minimal compilable example so that we can debug this.

Comment: @bob.sacamento   (1) Does what I posted change the behavior?  (2) When you print `funit` what do you get?  (3) Can you not put together a short complete program behaving this way?  That would take the guess work out of it.  (Also: it shouldn't matter, but what version of gfortran?)

Comment: @zdim  1) Yes, your solution works, but I still don't understand why my original code did not.  I have to move on so I am going with your solution.  2) Somehow, `funit` gets set to zero!?!?! This is with implicit none in place, BTW.  3) Not able so far to produce a code that produces the error and without including details that my employer would not want me putting on the internet.  Given the results others have obtained, looks like problem is elsewhere in the code.  If I can come back to this with a better example, I will.  gfortran 5.2.0.  Thanks.

Comment: @bob.sacamento  OK, so that confirms what everybody suspected: There are reasons elsewhere in the code. Passing it in is really a "fix," but it should be stable in my opinion. It sounds like that you _want to_ find a way to isolate the problem, for a long term piece of mind.  What if it bites in some other way as well?  (Btw, with 'implicit none' you are declaring it anew in that sub, with that scope, and that is something else.  I suggested that originally as an overall approach, as good practice.)

Comment: @bob.sacamento  Just to clarify 'implicit none' which I had mentioned originally and in comments.  (1) It is good practice, that was what I had in mind.  (2) It would relate to this problem only in this way:  When it is used in the routine, it declares a local copy of the variable, so it _forces one_ to explicitly consider what to do with that variable -- and, since we want to write to file that `funit` is associated with, `funit` _must be_ passed into the routine. So we don't rely on in-module 'global'. However, 'global' should work (in code that is shown!), the problem being elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this error if you don't have the proper permissions set on the file.